# VS2010 Setup and Deployment: removing a shortcut from previous version

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment

I have a VS2010 Setup and Deployment project. We have decided to change the program group to which the next version installs. How do I remove the previous program group? I would prefer to not have the user uninstall via Control Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to trigger the windows installer to peform a "Major Upgrade" of you product. A major upgrade will uninstall the previous versions components. Details can be found here ins the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786(v=vs.85).aspx

You might also consder moving to Wix (Windows Installer XML). You can create much more flexable installers in Visual Studio with it. See: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: My mistake. Turns out it was uninstalling the previous version. It was an issue of the Just Me or Everyone being different between the old and new version. Do you know if Wix could remove the old-Everyone shortcut if a new-Just Me was run? I would assume it can handle a new-Everyone, old-Just Me; since the new Everyone would require admin rights.